# How to identify different handlebar templates?

Tags: html, node.js, typescript, handlebars.js

I have several html files in my project which are templates to email messages, like email verification, password reset, etc...

I need to precompile these files and use them in the right place, for example, the email verification template must be sent in the registration function. The problem is how do I identify the templates to use them, given that I don't know from which type they are? How can I create some kind of identifier for the templates?

Comment: Please avoid adding capture screens and add the relevant source code. This helps a lot when answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your compiled templates in some data structure, returning it somehow and using it afterward.

Here down a sample based on your processing function and using `Map` as the data store:

```
export function preCompileTemplates(globString: string) {

  const paths = getPathsFromGlob(globString)

  const preCompiledTemplatesPs = paths.map(path => {
      const templateName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, path.length - 5);
      return fs.promises.readFile(path).then(template => {
          return {name: templateName, content: Handlebars.precompile(template)}
      })
  })

  const templates = new Map()
  return Promises.all(preCompiledTemplatesPs, (preCompiledTemplates) => {
    preCompiledTemplates.forEach(template => {
      templates.set(template.name, template.content)
    })
    return templates
  })
}
```